# Unable to renew Windows Azure SAS key in StorageException handler

Tags: .net, azure, exception, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm able to capture the "AuthenticationFailed" error code (in my catch block) from the StorageException when the SAS key expires.  I then make another call (within the catch block) to a SAS generation method to create a new SAS key with a later expiration.  When I have the new SAS key, I use it to make another CloudBlockBlob object to write the block that failed to the azure blob.  However, I keep getting the same "403 forbidden" authentication error I would get when the SAS key has expired.  Why is this happening when I'm creating a new CloudBlockBlob object with a different SAS key (with a later expiration)?  It has nothing to do with Clock skew since I don't even specify an "StartTime" in the SAS key generation.  Any ideas?  Is there a better practice for handling SAS renewal?  Would appreciate the help!  Below is my code.  NOTE:  I'm using javascript to chunk the upload, so each call to the WriteBlock method is a brand new state:

```
/// Sends the file chunk to the Azure Blob
/// <param name = "BlockId">The id for the current block</param name>
public void WriteBlockToBlob(string BlockId)
{
    try
    {
        Blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(BlobSasUri));

        Blob.PutBlock(
            BlockId,
            File.InputStream,
            null,
            null,
            uploadBlobOptions,
            null
        );
        /***********************************************************************************************/
        /* REST API Approach */
        //string queryString = (new Uri(abm.BlobContainerSasUri)).Query;
        //abm.BlobContainer = abm.BlobContainerSasUri.Substring(0, abm.BlobContainerSasUri.Length - queryString.Length);
        //string requestUri = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}{2}&comp=block&blockid={3}",
        //    abm.BlobContainer, abm.FileName, queryString, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(abm.BlockId)));
        //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        //request.Method = "PUT";
        //request.ContentLength = abm.File.InputStream.Length;
        //using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        //{
        //    inputStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
        //}
        //using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        //{
        //}
        /******************************************************************************************************/
    }
    catch (StorageException stex)
    {
        if (stex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode.Equals("AuthenticationFailed"))
        {
            AzureStorageTester ast = new AzureStorageTester();
            BlobSasUri = ast.getStorageLibrarySas(File.FileName);

            // Retry writing block to blob
            Blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(BlobSasUri));
            try
            {
                Blob.PutBlock(
                    BlockId,
                    File.InputStream,
                    null,
                    null,
                    uploadBlobOptions,
                    null
                );
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                var test = stex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode;
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        //string errMsg = ComposeAndLogStorageException(ExceptionFlag.UploadLargeFileException, stex);
        //BigFileExceptionFlag = "on";
        //throw new ApplicationException(errMsg);
    }
    catch (SystemException se)
    {
        string errMsg = ComposeAndLogSystemException(ExceptionFlag.UploadLargeFileException, se);
        BigFileExceptionFlag = "on";
        throw new ApplicationException(errMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMsg = ComposeAndLogException(ExceptionFlag.UploadLargeFileException, ex);
        BigFileExceptionFlag = "on";
        throw new ApplicationException(errMsg);
    }
    finally
    {
        File.InputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it has nothing to do with clock skew? You should confirm that by setting start time to something like (now - 5 minutes) just to rule it out.

Comment: @DavidMakogon:  Actually, I did do just that.  I set the start time to -5 minutes.  Still getting the same "AuthenticationFailed" error code.

Comment: Please post Blob SAS creation snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your debugging code is looking at the old exception instead of the new exception.

Change this:

```
var test = stex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode;
```

to this:

```
var test = ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode;
```

and try again to see what the new error code is.